# Start and Stop a MP3 File with Two Buttons - Possible?

Tags: android

I have an mp3 file that I would like to start with one button but stop with another. Is this possible? Here is my code to start the file on button1 - How would I stop the file on button2?

Thank you!

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    private MediaPlayer mplay;
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mplay == null){
       mplay = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.mysound);
       }
    mp.start();
    }             
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your `MediaPlayer` outside of your ClickListener -- as a class variable -- then handle starting and stopping in the click handling of your buttons, as they'll both be able to see it.

Comment: Yes, just make sure it's not null before you try to stop it ;-)

Comment: Thanks guys - I tried that but it doesnt like the 'Private' label and suggests 'Final'. Any ideas? Sorry for the newb questions...

Comment: For that, you can either make it final (and/or private -- it can be both) and handle changes to the track manually (going through the reset(), setDataSource(), prepare() procedure) which I would recommend doing anyway; or you can make your Activity implement View.OnClickListener and let the activity handle the onClick, then your MediaPlayer doesn't have to be a final variable.

Comment: Sorry guys its just not clicking. I created a: 'final MediaPlayer mplay;' but now the 'mplay's within the OnClick areas state 'mplay not initialized' - any ideas? THANKS!

Comment: Do you know what the `final` modifier does?

Comment: No - Im used to C++ where globals were a to more obvious - am I missing something here? Dont I just declare the global ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)

`final` is more or less `const`. You have to initialize it on declaration and it can't be changed later. Meaning you can't later say `mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create()`, you have to reuse the object as it is, reset() it back to default, set your data source (setDataSource()), then prepare it (prepare()), then you can play it again. You have to do this because you're creating a static inner class (View.OnClickListener) whereas if you just make the Activity implement the OnClickListener interface, you don't have to make the variable final.

Comment: Thanks so much! Finally got it to work thanks to all the great help!